# Как писать: ТОП или топ выдачи поисковиков?

Tags: орфография, заимствования

Как допустимо написать: попасть в **ТОП** выдачи поисковиков или в **топ**?

Comment: А зачем выделяют прописными часто?Это неправильно?

Comment: Для прописной нет никаких оснований сейчас. Это уже устоявшееся написание. Прописнаяу местна, если "топ" -условное наименование. Напр.: В журнале появилась статья "Топ-10 знаменитых фильмов".

Answer (score 1):

Корректно со строчной. 3. ТОП, -а; м. [англ. top - верх] Самое популярное, модное произведение, вещь (в одежде, эстрадной музыке и т.п.); список таких произведений. Т. музыканта. **Попасть в т.**

Большой толковый словарь русского языка.
Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов.
Первое издание: СПб.: Норинт, 1998.

Answer (score 1):

ДИАНА, прописными буквами пишут только аббревиатуры, да и то не все, и в некоторых случаях - слова, подлежащие дополнительному оформительскому выделению (на форумах, в соцсетях и вообще там, где иной способ выделения почему-то не удовлетворяет). Ни тем, ни другим наше "топ" не является. Даже не будь слово словарно зафиксировано, причин для прописных бы не было.

Возможно, вас смутило традиционное написание названий разного рода списков, линеек-опросов: ТОП-5, ТОП-20 и прочих. Но тут есть цифра, превращающая слово в имя собственное. Да и всё равно такое написание не очень соответствует орфографической норме.